# How do I print a '%' sign using string formatting?

Tags: python, printing, python-2.x, percentage

I've made a little script to calculator percent; however, I wish to actually include the `%` within the message printed...

Tried this at the start - didn't work...

```
oFile.write("Percentage: %s%"\n" % percent)
```

I then tried `"Percentage: %s"%"\n" % percent"` which didn't work.

I'd like the output to be:

```
Percentage: x%
```

I keep getting

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: @OliverW.: yes but that one's title and wording are very unclear, so this one should be canonical

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To print the `%` sign you need to 'escape' it with another `%` sign:

```
percent = 12
print "Percentage: %s %%\n" % percent  # Note the double % sign
>>> Percentage: 12 %
```

**EDIT**

Nowadays in python3 a better (and more readable) approach is to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). Note that other solutions (shown below) do work as well:

```py
$python3
>>> percent = 12
>>> print(f'Percentage: {percent}%') # f-string
Percentage: 12%
>>> print('Percentage: {0}%'.format(percent)) # str format method
Percentage: 12%
>>> print('Percentage: %s%%' % percent) # older format, we 'escape' the '%' character
Percentage: 12%
```

Comment: In some cases, like logging, f-strings are eagerly evaluated, while the old %s formatting is lazily evaluated - so f-strings are slower in these cases, which I would argue is not better for large code files.

Answer (score 13):

Or use `format()` function, which is more elegant.

```
percent = 12
print "Percentage: {}%".format(percent)
```

**4 years later edit**

Now In Python3x `print()` requires  parenthesis.

```
percent = 12
print ("Percentage: {}%".format(percent))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
x = 0.25
y = -0.25
print("\nOriginal Number: ", x)
print("Formatted Number with percentage: "+"{:.2%}".format(x));
print("Original Number: ", y)
print("Formatted Number with percentage: "+"{:.2%}".format(y));
print()
```

Sample Output:

```
Original Number:  0.25                                                                                        
Formatted Number with percentage: 25.00%                                                                      
Original Number:  -0.25                                                                                       
Formatted Number with percentage: -25.00%
```

Helps in proper formatting of percentage value

+++

Using ascii value of percentage - which is 37

```
print( '12' + str(chr(37)) )
```

Answer (score 4):

The new Python 3  approach is to use format strings.

```
percent = 12
print("Percentage: {0} %\n".format(percent))
>>> Percentage: 12 %
```

This is also supported in Python > 2.6.

See the docs here: [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and  [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Note that no need `0` inside bracelets

Comment: @howaboutNO `0` is required if you're using Py2.6

Comment: But that's *slightly more characters* than the nice modulos and my lazy 1st-world doesn't like typing characters to get results

Answer (score 2):

`format()` is more elegant but the modulo sign seems to be quicker!

http://inre.dundeemt.com/2016-01-13/string-modulo-vs-format-fight/ - shows that modulo is ~30% faster!

Answer (score -2):

```
print("Interest Rate (APR): " , format(APR, '.0f'),'%')
```

Comment: took this out of an interest calculator i made in class, this was the output:

Comment: Interest Rate (APR):  5 %

Comment: Please, add an explanation in your answer.