# Why is later double %% converted to single %

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
l='a'     
r='%sbb%%'%l    
print(r)
```

I expected the output `abb%%`, but the actual output is `abb%`.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: Think about it.  When `%` is used as a control character for substitutions in the string (_e.g._ `%s`), then you need a way to handle an _actual_ `%` character.  A single one indicates that the next character should indicate what data type is being substituted.  If that next character is a `%`, then it's interpreted as a `%` character with no substitution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a '%' sign using string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343745/how-do-i-print-a-sign-using-string-formatting)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The percent sign `%` is a special meta-character. I have described some examples below:

## INPUTS:

```
print("Hello %s %s. Your current balance is %.2f" % ("John", "Doe", 53.4423123123))
print("Hello, %s!" % "Bob")
print("%s is %d years old." % ("Sarah", 43))
print("Ian scored %.0f%s on the quiz." % (98.7337, "%"))
lyst = [1, 2, 3]
print("id(lyst) == %d" % id(lyst))
print("id(lyst) in hexadecimal format is %x" % id(lyst))
```

## OUTPUTS:

```
Hello John Doe. Your current balance is 53.44
Hello, Bob!
Sarah is 43 years old.
Ian scored 99% on the quiz.
id(lyst) == 58322152
id(lyst) in hexadecimal format is 379ece8
```

## NOTES:

```
+------+----------------------------------------------+
| %s   | String                                       |
| %d   | Integer                                      |
| %f   | Floating point number                        |
| %.2f | float with 2 digits to the right of the dot. |
| %.4f | float with 4 digits to the right of the dot. |
| %x   | Integers in hex representation               |
+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No part of your answer addresses the case the question is actually asking about, which is `%%`. (Just adding a `%%` example isn't going to help, because the question already has a `%%` example. You're going to need to actually explain things.)