# How to use multiple like filter '%' with psycopg '%'?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to get query results with multiple `like` filters, like this:

```
select *
from public.data 
where namep like '%YA%' and comm like '%comm' and state = %(region)s 
limit 10
```

But when I'm trying to execute this query with psycopg2 I'm getting the error:

> 'dict' object does not support indexing.

I found that this error occurs due to the first and second `like` statements with `'%'`. In my original query there several `'%'` symbols and `like` filter, so I can't change them.

I can't find any information,but is this possible to do some other filter for psycopg2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print a '%' sign using string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343745/how-do-i-print-a-sign-using-string-formatting)

Comment: ... you need to escape all 'static' occurrences of `%` by another `%`: `... where namep like '%%YA%%' ... `

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thanks,  your advice helped me, now it works