# How to print percentage at the beginning of string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I would like to create and print a string variable with a percentage sign at the beginning. I use Python 3.7.3, zeppelin and pyspark.

For example, I code:

```
%livy2.pyspark
a = '% some characters %'
print(a)
```

What I get:

```
some characters %
```

what I expect:

```
% some characters %
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Try adding `r'% string %'`, this defines it as a 'raw' string (escapes etc not interpreted)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The output is in fact `% some characters %` when running this code in a normal Python interpreter. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343745/how-do-i-print-a-sign-using-string-formatting

Comment: `a = 'some characters'; print(rf'% {a} %')` ?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's problem of zeppelin of python.

Comment: have you tried `print('%%' + a + '%%)`? Added the double % there just in case.

Comment: If all else fails, how about `sys.stdout.write('% some characters %\n')`?

Comment: Guys, thank you all for your replies. Unfortunetely even `sys.stdout.write('% some characters %\n')` doesn't work. Here is [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiKrd.png)

I believe it's zeppelin's error/bug.